# SimpleDateFormat returning current date or delayed by a month

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat

I am writing a simple code to get the date from server in UTC and then convert it to local time based on timeDiff noted earlier. Below is the simple code:

From App.Constants interface:

```
    SimpleDateFormat SDF_yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_SSS = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);


public String getEnddate(Context context) throws ParseException {
    Date date = App.Constants.SDF_yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_SSS.parse(enddate);
    Log.d("Check these dates", "Check dates EventEnd: " + enddate + date.toString());
    MyDate tmpDate = new MyDate(date); //May ignore this
    return tmpDate.toSQLite(App.getTimeDiff(context)); //May ignore this
}
```

Although the result I am getting are very funny. While 80% of the dates are getting converted right, at random:
1. In some cases SDF is returning current date and time
2. In some cases SDF is returning delayed by exactly a month.

Following is a selected dump of lines from Log. In first three instances below, date returned is the current date. In fourth instance, date is delayed by a month but the time returned is the current time. In the last instance, date returned is exactly delayed by a month from the original date.

01-01 21:33:30.869 24135-24135/? D/Check these dates: Check dates EventEnd: 20151222_003819_453Fri Jan 01 21:33:19 IST 2016

01-01 21:33:30.900 24135-24135/? D/Check these dates: Check dates EventEnd: 20151222_004950_104Fri Jan 01 21:33:50 IST 2016

01-01 21:33:30.961 24135-24135/? D/Check these dates: Check dates EventEnd: 20151226_235500_000Fri Jan 01 21:33:30 IST 2016

01-01 21:33:30.971 24135-24135/? D/Check these dates: Check dates EventEnd: 20151227_060800_000Wed Jan 27 21:33:00 IST 2016

01-01 23:17:07.977 31293-31293/? D/Check these dates: Check dates EventEnd: 20151222_195508_303Fri Jan 22 19:55:08 IST 2016
0

Hoping someone can help. Else, I am just getting too tempted to write my own String to Date converted. I really hope that I don't have to!!!

**EDIT**:
Was too impatient, and wrote the following parser real quick. With this parser, the code is working perfectly fine, as expected. But not with SimpleDateFormat.

```
public static Date localDateParser(String yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_SSS){
    int year = Integer.parseInt(yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_SSS.substring(0, 4));
    int month = Integer.parseInt(yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_SSS.substring(4, 6)) - 1;
    int day = Integer.parseInt(yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_SSS.substring(6, 8));

    int hour = Integer.parseInt(yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_SSS.substring(9, 11));
    int minute = Integer.parseInt(yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_SSS.substring(11, 13));
    int second = Integer.parseInt(yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_SSS.substring(13, 15));
//    int ms = Integer.parseInt(yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_SSS.substring(16));


    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
    new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()).toString());
    return new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
}
```

Comment: Can you print the orginal String?

Answer (score 0):

Plz change date.toString() to

App.Constants.SDF_yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_SSS.format(date).

Date.toString() is not working as you wish.

Comment: Nopes, It's not date.toString() that's the issue, have done toString() only to print the log. I am not using toString() anywhere else. Later in the code, I am comparing the dates returned, and am getting wrong result.. So SimpleDateFormat seems to be returning the wrong date. I am thoroughly perplexed.

Comment: Can you just try to use App.Constants.SDF_yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_SSS.format(date) instead of data.toString()?

Comment: In App.Constants.SDF_yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_SSS, Month is from 1 to 12.But in Date.toString() ,month is from 0 to 11.So 2015-12 becomes 2016-1.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but again, I don't think that's the issue. As I mentioned, out of the 40-50 odd entries, most of the entries are updated from String to date just fine. Randomly selected few give wrong result. Each time I run the app, it's different set that gives wrong conversion result. I have shared the log for only the entries that gave wrong result, not the entire log. If you see the EDIT I posted in my original request, it's working fine 100% of the time. No issues there..